# Ask: Ansible module to fetch speciffic value from source url

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

wondering if i miss something to use url module,
I'd like to use Ansible to download file from "https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/block-bad-queries.20220517.zip" - somehow that full urlpath available from source url of https://wordpress.org/plugins/block-bad-queries/ in `"downloadUrl": "https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/block-bad-queries.20220517.zip"`

I'm not quite sure if using url module can be used to fetch the value of downloadUrl or perhaps using something else to directly get the json data from that url, seems like i cant just use lookup url and using `urlresult.downloadUrl` as for finding tag from ansible

Many thanks in advance & appreciate it

Comment: What even is your question?

Comment: Can you provide a task or minimal playbook for testing? What kind of result you are getting?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for [url module for downloading](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/get_url_module.html)

Comment: Sorry for confusion, i mean i want to get the value of "downloadUrl" from https://wordpress.org/plugins/block-bad-queries/ and i currently test url module as well like below but seems i still mistakenly to understand for tags / json script inside the source url https://dpaste.org/EVORz

Answer (score 1):

It's much easier to get this information from [Wordpress API](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress.org_API#Plugins) which returns an easy to use json. The following demo playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    wp_plugin: block-bad-queries

  tasks:
    - name: Read plugin info from wordpress api json response
      uri:
        url: "https://api.wordpress.org/plugins/info/1.0/{{ wp_plugin }}.json"
      register: plugin_info

    - name: Display download uri from gathered plugion info
      debug:
        var: plugin_info.json.download_link

    - name: Download the plugin
      uri:
        url: "{{ plugin_info.json.download_link }}"
        dest: /tmp/
```

Gives

```
PLAY [localhost] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Read plugin info from wordpress api json response] ***************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Display download uri from gathered plugion info] *****************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "plugin_info.json.download_link": "https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/block-bad-queries.20220517.zip"
}

TASK [Download the plugin] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

PLAY RECAP *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

And simple check after running this playbook shows that the file is there:

```
$ ls -l /tmp/block-bad-*
-rw-r--r-- 1 user users 82113 sep 14 17:05 /tmp/block-bad-queries.20220517.zip
```